How did the author derive a string from a specific grammar?
Working on:

Richard Johnsonbaugh. (2018). Discrete Mathematics, 8/e (p. 608)

Given this grammar:
2. $T = \{a, b\}, N = \{\sigma, A, B\}$, with productions
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \sigma &\to A, & \sigma &\to AAB, & Aa &\to ABa, \\
    A &\to aa, & Bb &\to ABb, & B &\to b, \\
    AB &\to ABB,
\end{aligned}
$$
I have to derive the following string.

aabbaab

The solution given is:

How can I justify the following step?

$AAbb \Rightarrow AAAbb$

I don’t see a matching rule in the grammar.
P.S.: Of course, there is a mistake in the final derivation (Solution's manual).
EDIT:
Typo. The step should be:

$AAbb \Rightarrow AAABb$


The step you describe does not appear in the derivation given in the book.
However, I still think it contains two mistakes:
There is a step $AABB \Rightarrow AAbb$ followed by $AAbb \Rightarrow AAABb$.

the first one is not possible, because it needs to apply two rules at once ($B\to b$);
the second one is not possible because the number of terminals cannot decrease.

A simple patch would be to read this as $AABB \Rightarrow AABb \Rightarrow AAABb$, which use the rules $B\to b$ and $Bb\to ABb$.

Thank you so much, I will edit that derivation mistake and I understand your explanation
